# Alternative to Application.Volatile to auto update UDF

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function i got off of MSDN that counts the number of cells in a range that have a another cells color.

Here is the code

```
Function countCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        countCcolor = countCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

A requirement for this function is that it will update when ever a color value of a cell changes.

My idea is to create an event for when ever the color of a cell is changed and have it recalculate the any cell with the function but I'm not sure if this is the best way.

Answer (score 4):

You may have already found out that changing a cell's interior color doesn't fire a `Sub Worksheet_Change(...)`. As no value is changed, nothing gets recalculated. In this case not even the `Application.Volatile` is of help.

The best approach might be to use a `Worksheet_SelectionChange(...)`, eventually in combination with `Worksheet_Activate(...)` and `Worksheet_Deactivate(...)` (to have the sheet clean upon entry and leave) to call for an enforced recalculation, e.g.

```
Sub DoMyRecalc()
    ' Range("OutputRange").Calculate ' all uses of countCcolor() within that range
    ' [H3].Calculate                 ' countCcolor() only used in cell H3
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    DoMyRecalc
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    DoMyRecalc
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    DoMyRecalc
End Sub
```