# It is possible to trap AutoFilter as an Event?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to show the filter columns to users in the report. Excel gives a different icon but for large no. columns it will be good to color the columns in another color like blue.

I found code at [Is there a way to see which filters are active in Excel, other than just the funnel icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259641/is-there-a-way-to-see-which-filters-are-active-in-excel-other-than-just-the-fun)

- It works for me, but how do start this code without any button
- SheetChange and selection change do not work.

*code*

```
Sub test()
Call markFilter(ActiveSheet)
End Sub


Sub markFilter(wks As Worksheet)

    Dim lFilCol As Long

    With wks
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            For lFilCol = 1 To .AutoFilter.Filters.Count

                '/ If filter is applied then mark the header as bold and font color as red
                If .AutoFilter.Filters(lFilCol).On Then
                    .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(lFilCol).Cells(1, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                    .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(lFilCol).Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
                Else
                     '/ No Filter. Column header font normal and black.
                    .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(lFilCol).Cells(1, 1).Font.Color = vbBlack
                    .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(lFilCol).Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = False
                End If
            Next
        Else
            '/ No Filter at all. Column header font normal and black.
            .UsedRange.Rows(1).Font.Color = vbBlack
            .UsedRange.Rows(1).Font.Bold = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use the same example I used in the answer that you mentioned in your post. I answered that. :)

There is no filter change event in excel. One work-around that I would use is trapping the calculate method of the worksheet or better the workbook.

So, in the worksheet with filter add a dummy formula like this: `=SUBTOTAL(3,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100)` this counts only visible cells. But its up to you. Feel free to use any formula that responds to filter change.

[image]

After that, go to workbook's code and add this :

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
     Call markFilter(Sh)
     MsgBox "Filter changed"  
End Sub
```

Boom. Now you are trapping the filter change events and it will update the filtered columns by firing the vba code.

Note `markFilter` is coming from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39260309/3961708) that you mentioned.

Comment: Nice way to think outside the box.

Comment: Agreed. Your answer is best. Thanks for reviewing mine.:)

Comment: @cyboashu Is there a way to only trap calculation for say cell F11 and ignore any other calculation in the worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

The key points from my article [Trapping a change to a filtered list with VBA](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2773-Trapping-a-change-to-a-filtered-list-with-VBA.html)

1. A "dummy" WorkSheet is added with a single `SUBTOTAL` formula in `A1` pointing back to the range being filtered on the main sheet.
2. A `Worksheet_Calculate()` Event is added to the "dummy" WorkSheet, this Event fires when the `SUBTOTAL` formula updates when the filter is changed.

The next two steps are only needed if it is desired to run the Workbook Calculation as `Manual`

3. Add a `Workbook_Open` Event to set the `EnableCalculation` property of all sheets other than "Dummy" to False.
4. Run the Workbook in *Calculation* mode