# Execute a macro automatically when the linked cell of a combo box changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of 2 combo boxes. I have a macro called `Generate` which will change the options in the second combo box based on the number the first combo box returns. However this requires the user to press a button to execute this macro. I would like this macro to execute automatically when the number in the first combo box's linked cell changes.

This is the code I have previously tried, however the change in the link cell which is `B2` doesn't seem to trigger the event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then Generate
End Sub
```

Comment: A `Worksheet_Change` event only works when a cell is physically changed. Changes made by links or formulas do not constitute a physical change

Comment: here's a possible workaround for firing an event on change. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39260908/3961708

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution was to give the first combo box an input range and also assign it the `Generate` macro

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, a `Worksheet_Change` event will only be triggered by physically changing a cell, and thus your linked cell won't have any effect.

If it's a cell in another `wb` that needs to trigger your `Generate` Sub, then I'd advise using a Worksheet_Change event for said wb.

In my own project, I have a sub in a `regular module`:

```
Dim AddNew As Workbook
Set AddNew = Workbooks("") 'change this
Set oWb.Workbook = AddNew
```

Then, in a `class module`:

```
Public WithEvents m_wb As Workbook
Public Property Set Workbook(wb As Workbook)
Set m_wb = wb
End Property

Public Property Get Workbook() As Workbook
Set Workbook = m_wb
End Property

Public Sub m_wb_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
'In here, you could trigger the Generate Sub if a specific cell changes
End Sub
```