# Keep certain rows hidden on sheet2 based off sheet1 answers but allow filtering on sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

"I have an excel workbook where the user will fill out sheet1 with drop down list choices. Once they fill out the sheet1, they will click a button. That button will then look for specific keywords that I have determined on sheet1 and on sheet2 will then hide or keep visible certain questions related to the keywords and answer from sheet1. All of this appears to be functioning okay.

I got feedback from the users that they wanted to be able to filter the questions sheet2 (there is around 250 potential questions user needs to review on sheet2). When I allowed this feature (each sheet is protected with a password) I noticed when they used the filter feature on sheet2, the page would essentially "reset" sheet2 meaning all 250 questions are visible despite the  sheet1 button hiding specific questions depending on what was filled out in sheet1.

My question is, is there a way I can still have users be able to filter the questions but also still keeping the questions that are not necessary (based off sheet1 input) hidden when using the filter feature and the "Clear Filter From "x""?

Comment: You can detect the filter and re-hide the relevant rows.  See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260841/it-is-possible-to-trap-autofilter-as-an-event

Comment: ...or move the hidden question to a different sheet (which could itself be hidden)