# Range of filtered Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have  filtered a range on a criteria.

Now I need the address of the filtered range to use in a Vlookup function.

I am using this, but it returns two ranges - the filtered range and the header row range. How can I get the address of filtered range without the header row?

```
 Set filteredRng = wbCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
```

Comment: Is that off a `ListView` table? If so, use that instead of `.CurrentRegion`.

Comment: Will it be a problem to include the header-row also in vlookup function..  I never had any issues earlier.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39260652/4539709

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the filtered range without the header row:

```
With wbCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    Set filteredRng = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlVisible)
End With
```

To get its address:

```
With wbCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    filteredRngAddress= .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Address
End With
```