# Locate Excel filters easily

Tags: excel, filter

How can easily identify the pre-filtered columns in excel without having to scroll to see them?
I get excel document that has MANY columns (almost 64) and pre-filtered with different columns every time. Let us say that columns AC and AQ have filters on. I have to scroll from column A to the end of the columns to check which columns have the filter turned on (i.e. highlighted in BLUE). Instead, ....
I need a short cut (Hot function key or something similar) that will identify all the columns that are being filtered (i.e. columns AC and AQ) - May be a function key that will go from filtered column to another filtered column,...etc. I know I can take off the filters off completely but I do not want that. I just need to see which filter is active.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489126/in-excel-vba-how-do-i-save-restore-a-user-defined-filter

Comment: Is the data in raw format or formatted as a table (i.e. with Ctrl+T)?

Comment: The answers to this question may be of help: [Is there a way to see which filters are active in Excel, other than just the funnel icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39259641/14148248)