# How do I Check for a Filter in a Certain Column then Filter/Unfilter it?

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I have two filters in a spreadsheet and I am attempting to check if one of them is active(Column H). If it is filtered I only want to unfilter on that column, if it isn't I want to apply the Filter.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub UnFilter()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

  Set ws = Worksheets("Ranked Results")
  With ws
    If Not Intersect(.AutoFilter.Range, .Range("H1")) Is Nothing Then
      .Range("$A$2:$K$22003").AutoFilter Field:=8
    Else
      Dim Company As String
      Company = .Range("L2")
     .Range("$A$2:$K$22003").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">" & Company, _
     Operator:=xlAnd
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259641/is-there-a-way-to-see-which-filters-are-active-in-excel-other-than-just-the-fun